# How to use lambdas in "template"

Tags: java

I have an event handling code, something like

```
void handleEventType1(EventType1 event1) {
    if (someCheck()){
        function1(event);
        postCheckTrue();
    } else {
        function2(event);
        postCheckFalse();
    }
}

void handleEventType2(EventType2 event2) {
    if (someCheck()){
        function3(event);
        postCheckTrue();
    } else {
        function4(event);
        postCheckFalse();
    }
}
```

I was hoping, I can do something like

```
handleEvent(event1, Handler::function1, Handler::function2);
handleEvent(event2, Handler::function3, Handler::function4);
```

that will somehow call functions (1 or 2) or (3 or 4), but I'm somehow not able to solve it to my satisfaction.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: FYI: pseudocode is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets use inheritance. We will inherit the specific event types from the event interface.

```
interface Event {}

class EventType1 implements Event{}

class EventType2 implements Event{}
```

Secondly, lets define the type of functions that we will call in the handleEvent() method. In this case it is `Consumer<Event>`

Now our handleEvent() function will look like this

```
void handleEvent(Event event, 
                 Consumer<Event> option1, 
                 Consumer<Event> option2) {
   if (someCheck()) {
      option1.accept(event);
   } else {
       option2.accept(event);
   }
}
```

Now we can call this function and pass instance of event interface and two lambdas or method references

```
Handler.handleEvent(new EventType1(),
    event -> {
       //do something
    }, 
    event -> {
       //do something else;
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight I may have misunderstood something, but the author asked a question that I answered. He asked how to do what he wants, I showed how it can be done. If the question itself or my answer is irrelevant for this site, then you need to close it and forget about it. Sorry, maybe I should read the rules carefully. However, I provided assistance to the author.

Comment: The question is off-topic (psuedo/hypothetical/example), so you would have been better leaving this one unanswered.

Comment: Thank you, I understood